# Pentaho cant access cde samples

Tags: pentaho

I want to develop dashboard with cde. But when I want to start with it, error appears and this is the error message "Object type XDashFusionChartComponent can't be mapped to a valid class".

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you installed CDE? It sounds like you're trying to view a dashboard that uses Fusion Chart components, so I need a little more context here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a recent version of biserver like 4.5 or newer, download Pedro Alves' ctools-installer script. Follow the instruction. You can download the script anywhere (it does not have to be in a specific directory).

The script will allow you to install every single CTools available, and to use CDE, you have to install CDA.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not install CDE and CDF dashboard.